# Unknown spreading weed

Tags: lawn, weed-control

[image]I live in Eastern NC. I have a pink flowering plant (weed) all over my lawn. It grows and starts expending each plants width. The pink flowering plant eventually turns brown and turns into hard painful thorns that stick into shoes and pets feet and end up indoors.  I've gone to gardening centers and had a lawn care company identify it as different things and they have spread weed killer to no avail. What is it and how can I get rid of it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it have fruit? What is the colour and size?

Comment: For the sake of clarity, its probably that both Karol's and Jurp's answers are correct.  Dead-nettle is part of the Lamiaceae - also known as the mint - family of plants.

Comment: It has no fruit. The plant is green, the flower pink. They are small but as it matures it gets bigger and bigger. Not tall but spread like flat octopus tentacles, up to 6-8 or more inches across.  The photo was clear but I kept getting messages saying it's too big to post and I kept zooming it.  The sharp needle like things come in summer and stick in feet or shoes and hurt like hell. 
Isn't Roundup dangerous to use?  I've been out for 2 weeks ripping them out of the ground, but there are many hundreds.

Comment: I've added further comment and I believe two more photos. Sorry, I'm not the most computer savvy person

Comment: What kind of weed killer have you/they tried?  Standard weedkiller for lawns, may not kill it, but Glysophate probably will. (yeah yeah, save the bees etc).

Comment: I'm not sure what they tried. It was lawn doctor I used and they tried spraying and it killed some but not all of it.

Comment: I just tried adding a better photo of the tiny flower that forms, as well as a bit of the leaf

Comment: @Vinnie the latest photos are very good, thanks.

Comment: Are you positive that the thorns are coming from that plant? That plant looks like one that does not produce thorns.

Comment: TY I tried to get better ones.
Yes I'm sure, but only as spring ends. I was pulling them out last year and had to wear gloves because I immediately was stuck and had to get it out with tweezers. I can't get photos of the "thorns" until summer. They are not long and pointed, they are sort of small rectangular with pointed ends.  That's the best I can describe them.  I'm having the same problem here I had asking lawn places. So many ideas what this plant is. Someone suggested using Roundup. I've never used it before or any weed killer myself, but isn't round up the one with many health issues?

Comment: From your description it sounds like the "thorns" are dried seed capsules. There is a close up photo of those here: https://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/WEEDS/henbit.html

Comment: Concerning herbicides. A page with herbicide info specific to this plant: https://growiwm.org/weeds/henbit/

However, please note that almost all lamiums are beneficial plants, both for pollinators and your lawn environment. It is also an edible plant (free food!). Using herbicides on the other hand may affect your health and devastates the ecosystem of your garden. Consider keeping the plant and managing it by manual intervention.

Comment: It looks like this is the right plant. I have over an acre of land and this stuff covers it all over. I believe you are right that it's seeds that are sticking to me. They are VERY sharp, and stick in shoes, feet & hands. My cat has a hard time walking because they stick in his feet also. I don't have any garden, just a lawn. To try weeding the thousands around would be nearly impossible as it's everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [henbit dead-nettle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamium_purpureum) to me.

**Update**: I put in the wrong link above, to *lamium purpureum* also known as red or purple dead-nettle. I meant [common/greater henbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamium_amplexicaule), as I wrote, which is *lamium amplexicaule* and closely related. The distinguishing feature are the amplexicaul or "grapsing" leaves that surround the stem at their base; purple henbit has apical leaves or hanging on their own mini-stems. Your first close-up of the flower clearly shows the former. I found [this page](https://www.canr.msu.edu/news/purple_deadnettle_and_henbit_two_common_garden_spring_weeds) that nicely explains the differences at length (there are a few more).

Comment: Does not really look like that to me. Maybe Glechoma, maybe some other similar american Lamiaceae but does not look like Lamium purpureum too much.

Comment: The picture does, but what the question describes about thorns doesn't match at all, so the questioner might be dealing with multiple weeds and conflating them.

Comment: No, it's one plant all over my lawn. They grow in bunches on my lawn. And I know it's the same plant all over because when I pull it out by hand the thorns stick in my fingers

Comment: The thorns were describing the dry seeds, not the stem. I'm not familiar with the seeds enough, but I wouldn't be surprised if nettle seeds dry into frustrating thorn-like shapes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the obviously square stems on one shoot, plus the flowers (although blurry), you have a mint of some kind, which means it's spreading via the roots and any stem that touches the soil. RoundUp will kill it, but you will have to apply it more than once in order to kill all of the roots.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers make sense based on the color of the weed in the picture (and looking at it again, it looks like there may be pictures of two separate plants? The first photo does indeed look like a dead nettle, but they don't produce thorns of any kind), but not the description of the spreading habits or the painful seeds. The question does not describe the shape of the "thorns", but it sounds like [common stork's-bill or Erodium cicutarium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erodium_cicutarium) to me, which produces seeds with a sharp point on one end and a curling tail on the other that helps them dig into the soil (and incidentally, anything else they might come in contact with, as they're slightly barbed).

Here are a couple of images from the above linked Wikipedia article:

[image: Growth habit]

[image: Seeds]

And one from [Calflora](https://www.calflora.org/app/taxon?crn=3448) showing the rosette growth habit:
[image: Rosette growth]

The leaves in the original question don't quite match, so it may be a close relative of this plant instead. As far as I am aware, several have similarly painful seeds, but I am not sure which specific ones might be found in NC.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly ground-ivy, Latin name *Glechoma hederacea*. The Wikipedia page is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glechoma_hederacea).

Comment: The leaves on this look different.  The closest I've seen, which I think it is, is Karol's comment.

Comment: @Vinnie - yes, I think you're right.